# Apache PDFBox - Adding multiple fonts

Tags: pdfbox

Is there anyway we can add multiple fonts to Apache PDFBox? In our app, showing text in Browser works because browser uses multiple fonts to render a page. We are trying to mimic the same when generating PDF out of the data displayed in the browser but running into many Glyph errors like the one below.

> No glyph for U+0633 in font XXXXX

I see iText offers this utility where we can add multiple fonts

`fontSelector.addFont(new Font(Fonts.FONT_NOTO_SANS, size, style, color));
 fontSelector.addFont(new Font(Fonts.FONT_NOTO_SANS_AR, size, style, color));
 fontSelector.addFont(new Font(Fonts.FONT_NOTO_SANS_TH, size, style, color));
 fontSelector.addFont(new Font(Fonts.FONT_NOTO_SANS_CJK, size, style, color));`

But with PDFbox, I do not see a way to add base font and backup fonts where all characters are not available from single font file especially when we have a mix of English, Foreign language characters, numbers, spaces etc...

`PDType0Font.load(document, new File(loc));`

Comment: PDFBox text drawing operations are all very low level. In particular you have to explicitly set the font to use for drawing the next piece of text yourself. What you can do is create a functionality yourself which scans the characters of the string you want to draw and checks which font to use and then creates an appropriate match of font setting and text drawing instructions.

Comment: Thanks mkl. Will try that option. For setting the font, we load the font at document level and set the font at every header, sub header, text based on regular or bold fonts. I agree with you that it is very low level but we have licensing issues to use iText.

Comment: *"we have licensing issues to use iText."* - Well, I suppose that means management does neither want to pay for a commercial license nor provide your software as required by AGPL. PDFBox is a good library, too, but with a different focus. Whether using it for a task not that much in its focus (here: generating dynamically styled layout'ed text) just to not pay for some license fees will eventually pay out, remains to be seen...

Comment: :) Totally agree